# UpdateExpression DynamoBD to Append Items to a List only if they are Unique (avoid duplicates)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

The basic setup is to have a Key Value Pair where the Key is an ElementID and the Values is a list of all the locations in which that Element is present.

using boto3 libraries, with the table.update_item(), but the important part is the update expression.

The farthest I got was

```
"SET locations = list_append(if_not_exists(locations, :newlocations), :newlocations)"
```

Which doesn't seem to work.

The goal is that if you have an Element that already exists in DynamoDB, with a location list of {file0,file1,file2}, that if you update with {file2,file3}, it will just add file3 and not duplicate file2

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work, because if the attribute "locations" already exists, `if_not_exists` just takes to it, and the `list_append` will append to it `:newlocations`, without any de-duplication happening.

If you want de-duplication, you should not be using a **list** - you should be using a **set**, which similar to a list but different, and just like you wanted, eliminates duplicate values. To add items to a set, just use the update expression `ADD locations :newlocations`.

That's it - you don't need `list_append` (which only works for lists, not sets), nor `if_not_exists` (the `ADD` operation already works correctly for a non-existent item or attribute  and creates it).

Comment: How to represent a set in JSON in DynamoDb? I believe this is not possible, and thus your answer will be wrong. Please let me know if I am wrong.

Comment: Sets are definitely one of the supported data types in DynamoDB. Check out "Sets" in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.NamingRulesDataTypes.html